# Set iOS in app purchase is consumable

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an application that has In App Purchase method. When I go to Manage In App Purchase section on iTunesConnect, I add some product for In App Purchase. But I just see 1 option is Free Subscription. How can I add a product for Consumable? Sorry for my bad English writing skill and thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to add in-app purchase, I see this screen. It's not have Consumable option. I don't know what is my issue? :(

You need to go to Tax, contracts and banking and accept paid applications agreement

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When trying to add an in-app purchase you will be taken to this screen. Select the consumable type

[image: In-app purchase type]

Answer (score 0):

If a type is missing, make sure you have agreed to all recent contracts.Before you create In-App Purchases on app you have to provide information about "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa. Look at the image below.[image]

Just click on "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" and give all bank details.Once you provided bank details you can add all type of In-App Purchase.[image]